# Ceiling and flooring proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or disprove :

$ \left\lceil \frac { \left\lceil \frac { x }{ 2 }  \right\rceil  }{ 2 }  \right\rceil =\left\lceil \frac { x }{ 4 }  \right\rceil \quad for\quad all\quad real\quad numbers\quad x $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $\left\lceil\frac{x}4\right\rceil=n$, so that $n-1<\frac{x}4\le n$.

- What are the possible values of $\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil$?
- What value(s) of $\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil}2\right\rceil$ do they yield?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to do it. Our professor is so bad and i can't understand the textbook's explanation. I would appreciate if you fully explained it to me

Comment: @Tennisman: You know that $n-1<\frac{x}4\le n$, so $2n-2<\frac{x}2\le 2n$. From that inequality you should be able to identify the two integers that are possible values of $\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil$.

Comment: @Tennisman: Try a specific value of $n$, say $n=3$, so that $2<\frac{x}4\le 3$, i.e., $8<x\le 12$. Then $4<\frac{x}2\le 6$. What are the only two integers that $\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil$ could possibly be?

Comment: Could be 5 and 6 ?

Comment: @Tennisman: Exactly right. If $8<x\le 10$, it’s $5$, and if $10<x\le 12$, it’s $6$. When you divide $5$ and $6$ by $2$, you get $2.5$ and $3$, and when you take the ceiling, you get $3$ in both cases, which is $\left\lceil\frac{x}4\right\rceil$. Now you just have to generalize that idea from the specific case $n=4$ to general $n$.

Comment: Sorry i got confused. Now we have $ \left\lceil \frac { x }{ 2 }  \right\rceil $ could be 5 and 6.  Why would i divide 5 and 6 by 2 ?

Comment: @Tennisman: Because you want to know what $\left\lceil\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil}2\right\rceil$ is, and for that you need to look at $\frac{\left\lceil\frac{x}2\right\rceil}2$.

Comment: Ahhh :D sorry i even forgot the question :) Thank you for your help :)